# How to disable top left hotspot corner in KDE?

Tags: kde, arch-linux

I'm using KDE 4.7 (from the `testing` repo) on Arch Linux 3.0-ARCH.  It's very annoying that when I move my mouse to the top left, thumbnails of my windows appear.

This is especially annoying with Firefox, I made it borderless so I can click on the tabs easily, I just have to move my mouse to the top.

How do I disable that hotspot?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is done in **Screen Edges** System Settings Module.

Fire up the Application Menu, type "edge" there and open the search result.

Then click on the top-left corner of the display picture and select "No Action". Press <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image: Screen Edges - System Settings Module]

You can also start this application from the terminal:

```
kcmshell5 kwinscreenedges
```

Comment: In current KDE (5.8.x) it seems the command is `kcmshell5 kwinscreenedges`.

Comment: @Oleh Is it possible to make it behave like macOS? I mean, to show it when I do three fingers scroll on track pad.

Answer (score 0):

In System Settings, search for "edges". That will gray out almost all of the icons, leaving "Desktop Behavior" looking normal. Click on that, and one of the icons in the sidebar will be called "screen edges".